# How to build jacoco test report task in Kotlin (Gradle 5)

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle

I have this Groovy script that I would like to convert into Kotlin (`build.gradle.kts`). Can somebody help me out or give me a pointer?

Groovy (works):

```
    task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
        group = "Reporting"
        description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"
        reports {
            xml.enabled = true
            html.enabled = false
            csv.enabled = false
        }
        def fileFilter = ['**/BuildConfig.class', 'src/main/gen/**/*', 'src/main/assets/**/*',]
        def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: fileFilter)
        def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main"
        sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
        classDirectories = files([debugTree])
        executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ['**/**/*.exec', '**/**/*.ec'])
    }
```

Kotlin (my failed attempt, does not work):

```
    tasks.register("jacocoTestReport", JacocoReport::class) {
        group = "Reporting"
        description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

        this.reports.csv.setEnabled(false)
        this.reports.html.setEnabled(false)
        this.reports.xml.setEnabled(true)
        val debugTree = fileTree("${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes").filter { file ->
            return@filter file.absolutePath.startsWith("src/main/gen/") ||
                    file.absolutePath.startsWith("src/main/assets/") ||
                    file.absoluteFile.endsWith("BuildConfig.class")
        }
        val mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main"
        sourceDirectories.setFrom(files(mainSrc))
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(debugTree))
        val executionTree = fileTree(project.projectDir).filter { file ->
            return@filter !(file.absoluteFile.endsWith(".exec") || file.absoluteFile.endsWith(".ec"))
        }
        executionData.setFrom(executionTree)
    }
```

**Update:** This may work. That no XML is created is not related to the content of the script. See accepted answer. But anyway, the accepted answer is a more logical rewrite.

Comment: What's the problem with your Kotlin attempt? Any specific exceptions?

Comment: So the problem is that no XML file is created

Comment: Is there a way to execute the same logic as in Groovy with the wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
tasks.register("jacocoTestReport", JacocoReport::class) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    reports {
        csv.isEnabled = false
        html.isEnabled = false
        xml.isEnabled = true
    }

    sourceDirectories.setFrom(files("${project.projectDir}/src/main"))
    classDirectories.setFrom(
            fileTree("${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes") {
                setExcludes(setOf("**/BuildConfig.class", "src/main/gen/**/*", "src/main/assets/**/*"))
            }
    )
    executionData.setFrom(
            fileTree(project.projectDir) {
                setIncludes(setOf("**/**/*.exec", "**/**/*.ec"))
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: It seems to gather coverage correctly. One problem that I see is that it won't respect the flags. I have set `xml.isEnabled = true` and `html.isEnabled = false` but still get HTML reports and no XML

Comment: What about your syntax? (`this.reports.csv.setEnabled(false)`)?

Comment: Actually, I found out that it worked when I moved the code to the submodule definition. So the problem was not related to the task definition. Your example worked @madhead. Thanks.